# Почему картинка не растягивается на весь экран?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

У меня есть слайдер, вот [здесь](https://codepen.io/NeZoX/details/XBBdXQ/)

```
<!--  main-slider -->
<div class='main-slider'>
    <!-- main-slider chevrons -->
    <button class='main-slider__chevron-left main-slider__chevron'><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button class='main-slider__chevron-right main-slider__chevron'><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>

     <div class='slidewrapper' data-current = '0'>
        <div class='slidewrapper__container'>
            <img src="http://bsnscb.com/data/out/163/39872064-restaurant-wallpapers.jpeg" class='slidewrapper__img'>

            <div class='slidewrapper__container-phrase'>Awesome taste</div>
        </div>
        <div class='slidewrapper__container'>
            <img src="http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/restaurant_cafe_design_style_tables_chairs_39235_1920x1080.jpg" class='slidewrapper__img'>

            <div class='slidewrapper__container-phrase'>Cozy atmosphere</div>
        </div>
        <div class='slidewrapper__container'>
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1882327.jpg" class='slidewrapper__img'>

            <div class='slidewrapper__container-phrase'>The best chefs</div>
        </div>
     </div><!-- /slidewrapper -->
</div><!--  /main-slider -->

/* 

START Main-slider

*/
.main-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2c3e50;

    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
    /* Main-slider chevrons*/
    .main-slider:hover .main-slider__chevron-right {
        right: -10px;
    }
    .main-slider:hover .main-slider__chevron-left {
        left: -10px;
    }

    .main-slider__chevron {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        outline: none;
        background-color: #1e272e;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        z-index: 11;

        position: absolute;
        top: 175px;

        -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
           -moz-transition: 0.2s ease;
            -ms-transition: 0.2s ease;
             -o-transition: 0.2s ease;
                transition: 0.2s ease;
    }
    .main-slider__chevron:hover {
        opacity: 0.95;
    }
     .main-slider__chevron-right {
        border-top-left-radius: 25px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;

        right: -50px;
     }
     .main-slider__chevron-left {
        border-top-right-radius: 25px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;

        left: -50px;
     }


    .slidewrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
    }       
         /* Main-slider container */
         .slidewrapper__container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;

            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
         }
        /* Main-slider phrase */
        .slidewrapper__container-phrase {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            color: white;
            line-height: 40px;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-family: Lobster;
            display: inline-block;


            padding: 5px 10px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 70px;
        }
        .slidewrapper__container-phrase:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
            cursor: default;
        }
        /* Main-slider images */
        .slidewrapper__img {
            width: 100%;

            height: auto;

        /*  background-clip: border-box;
            background-origin: padding-box; 
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat; 
            background-size: cover;*/
        }
/* Media quaries */
@media (max-width: 782px) {
 .main-slider {
     top: 25px;
 } 
}

/* 

END main-slider

*/

      var 
      slideHeight = jQuery('.main-slider').height(),
      sliderTimer;

  jQuery( function () {
      jQuery('.slidewrapper').width(jQuery('.slidewrapper').children().length * slideHeight);
      sliderTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);

      jQuery('.main-slider__chevron').hover( 
          function () {
              clearInterval(sliderTimer);
          },
          function(){
              sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
          });
  });

  function nextSlide () {
      var 
          currentSlide = parseInt(jQuery('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
      currentSlide++;

      if(currentSlide >= jQuery('.slidewrapper').children().length) {
          currentSlide = 0;   
      }

      jQuery('.slidewrapper').animate({top: -currentSlide * slideHeight}, 300).data('current', currentSlide);
  }

  function prevSlide () {
      var 
          currentSlide = parseInt(jQuery('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
      currentSlide--;

      if(currentSlide < 0) {
          currentSlide = jQuery('.slidewrapper').children().length - 1;   
      }

      jQuery('.slidewrapper').animate({top: -currentSlide * slideHeight}, 300).data('current', currentSlide);
  }

  jQuery('.main-slider__chevron-left').click(function() {
      prevSlide();
  });
  jQuery('.main-slider__chevron-right').click(function() {
      nextSlide();
  });
```

И почему-то изображения в нём не растягиваются на весь слайдер. Ума не приложу где находится ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в скрипте блоку `.slidewrapper` задается фиксированая ширина. Измените или удалите вот эту строку.

`jQuery('.slidewrapper').width(jQuery('.slidewrapper').children().length * slideHeight);`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо было сделать простое обнуление стилей

```js
var
  slideHeight = jQuery('.main-slider').height(),
  sliderTimer;

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.slidewrapper').width(jQuery('.slidewrapper').children().length * slideHeight);
  sliderTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);

  jQuery('.main-slider__chevron').hover(
    function() {
      clearInterval(sliderTimer);
    },
    function() {
      sliderTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
    });
});

function nextSlide() {
  var
    currentSlide = parseInt(jQuery('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
  currentSlide++;

  if (currentSlide >= jQuery('.slidewrapper').children().length) {
    currentSlide = 0;
  }

  jQuery('.slidewrapper').animate({
    top: -currentSlide * slideHeight
  }, 300).data('current', currentSlide);
}

function prevSlide() {
  var
    currentSlide = parseInt(jQuery('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
  currentSlide--;

  if (currentSlide < 0) {
    currentSlide = jQuery('.slidewrapper').children().length - 1;
  }

  jQuery('.slidewrapper').animate({
    top: -currentSlide * slideHeight
  }, 300).data('current', currentSlide);
}

jQuery('.main-slider__chevron-left').click(function() {
  prevSlide();
});
jQuery('.main-slider__chevron-right').click(function() {
  nextSlide();
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}


/* Main-slider chevrons*/

.main-slider:hover .main-slider__chevron-right {
  right: -10px;
}

.main-slider:hover .main-slider__chevron-left {
  left: -10px;
}

.main-slider__chevron {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #1e272e;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  z-index: 11;
  position: absolute;
  top: 175px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.main-slider__chevron:hover {
  opacity: 0.95;
}

.main-slider__chevron-right {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  right: -50px;
}

.main-slider__chevron-left {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  left: -50px;
}

.slidewrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}


/* Main-slider container */

.slidewrapper__container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Main-slider phrase */

.slidewrapper__container-phrase {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Lobster;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 70px;
}

.slidewrapper__container-phrase:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
}


/* Main-slider images */

.slidewrapper__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: padding-box; 
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;*/
}


/* Media quaries */

@media (max-width: 782px) {
  .main-slider {
    top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main-slider'>
  <!-- main-slider chevrons -->
  <button class='main-slider__chevron-left main-slider__chevron'><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
  <button class='main-slider__chevron-right main-slider__chevron'><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>

  <div class='slidewrapper' data-current='0'>
    <div class='slidewrapper__container'>
      <img src="http://bsnscb.com/data/out/163/39872064-restaurant-wallpapers.jpeg" class='slidewrapper__img'>

      <div class='slidewrapper__container-phrase'>Awesome taste</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slidewrapper__container'>
      <img src="http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/restaurant_cafe_design_style_tables_chairs_39235_1920x1080.jpg" class='slidewrapper__img'>

      <div class='slidewrapper__container-phrase'>Cozy atmosphere</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slidewrapper__container'>
      <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1882327.jpg" class='slidewrapper__img'>

      <div class='slidewrapper__container-phrase'>The best chefs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /slidewrapper -->
</div>
<!--  /main-slider -->
```

Comment: Не помогло. Картинки всё равно не растянулись по всей ширине слайдера.